# Why is indexOf returning an incorrect index?

Tags: java

I'm baffled as to why `posOfDot` is returning 15:

```
for(String l2 : list2){

    System.out.println("l2FileNAme: "+l2);
    int posOfI= l2.indexOf("_")+1;
    System.out.println("posOfI: "+posOfI);

    String l2FileName = l2.substring(0,posOfI);
    System.out.println("l2FileNAme: "+l2FileName);

    for(String l1 : list1){

        int posOfDot= l2.indexOf(".");
        System.out.println("posOfDot: "+posOfDot);
        //substring the root of the file
        //String l1FileName = l1.substring(0,posOfDot); //fails here as posOfDot exceeds string length in substring.
        System.out.println("l1FileNAme: "+l1);  
    }
}
```

Output:

```
l2FileNAme: scenario8_items.txt
posOfI: 10
l2FileNAme: scenario8_
posOfDot: 15
l1FileNAme: scenario8_.csv
```

I'm expecting posOfDot to be 10, just like the posOfI, yet it returns 15. How come?

What I've tried:

- lastIndexOf
- indexOf
- both char notation and string notation ('' and "")

--EDIT--

Each list (list1 and list2) contain a listing of filenames. These are not the actual file itself, but rather just the filename.

Comment: How are we supposed to know what's in those files?

Comment: I'm not searching the file - I'm searching the filename.

Comment: Maybe using the correct `String` would produce better results? Prime example of why not to name variables like that, even when you *think* nothing could possibly go wrong. `int posOfDot= l2.indexOf(".");` - that's *exactly* where the `.` is in `l2`

Comment: Why would you expect it to be 10? posOfI is returning the position of the underscore. posOfDot is returning the position of the period. Do they look like they're in the same spot to you? The look like they're separated by 5 characters to me. Factor in the +1 you do on the posOfI and there's your difference.

Comment: Your inner loop isn't doing anything very useful with l1 other than print it

Comment: It has clearly been a long day lol - Thank you everyone for pointing out what should have been blatantly obvious.

Comment: @peter.murray.rust I know :-) I have other logic that wasn't relevant to the question based upon that loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
l2FileNAme: scenario8_items.txt
```

Counting the characters on the screen, the `.` is in the 16th place, which is 15 in a zero-based indexing.  You're performing this on `l2`.

Seems like the correct output to me.